# xcalib error -> unsupported ramp size -> Missing letters in menus and folder names

Tags: xorg, display, intel-graphics, colors, xcalib

When issuing xcalib commands I was getting the error `Error - unsupported ramp size 0`. I was able to fix this by creating the following file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and placing this text inside the file

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

This created a new issue, Nautilus omits random letters when displaying filenames, directories, menu entries, etc (see below). This is solved by adding a line `Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"` to my `20-intel.conf` which unfortunately slows everything down, considerably.

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

What's going on and what's the best way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: @DK Bose no this is a different Ubuntu Bionic Beaver machine, different from the `Desktop folders won't open with clean install of 18.04` issue. At first I was trying to simply use xcalib and would get the `unsupported ramp size` error. Fixing that then led to the `Missing letters in menus etc` error. If I could fix `xcalib unsupported ramp size` without having to create `20-intel.conf` file I'd be good.

Comment: Given that there are performance issues that seem to be associated with fixing `xcalib` ramp issue, could you explain what you want to use `xcalib` for? Maybe there's a better alternative not requiring `xcalib`? Also why did you prefer `uxa` and not `sna`?

Comment: @DK Bose Didn't know `sna` existed so will definitly give that a go. If `sna` is the default acceleration method, it makes Nautilus drop letters in filenames/menu_entries as shown in pic above. I simply want to invert my desktop colors for easy night reading. `xcalib -i -a` seemed like the easiest solution but I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: I played briefly with xcalib, but the problem with `-i` is that while white becomes black, black becomes white! I even played with `-co` but finally went with a dark gtk color scheme for all applications (and "dark" style sheets for browser pages) that I use day and night together with `sct 4500` for night.